# Regular Expression with Python (pattern with character exception)

Tags: python, regex

Please I tried to create a pattern that can index some references, but I have a case that is hard for me to separate.

```
line = "thiêu (30:33). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6 việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38)."
```

```
line = re.sub(r'([^–])(\d+):(\d+)([^\\|–|\}|\d])(\d+)', r'\1\2:\3\4\5\\index[KT]{?@?!0\2|0\3 @\2:\3\4\5}', line)
print("12 => ", line)
line = re.sub(r'([^–])(\d+):(\d+)(?!\-)', r'\1\2:\3\\index[KT]{?@?!0\2|0\3 @\2:\3}', line)
print("13 => ", line)
```

Return

```
12 =>  thiêu (30:33). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6 việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38\index[KT]{?@?!037|036 @37:36-38}).
13 =>  thiêu (30:33\index[KT]{?@?!030|033 @30:33}). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6\index[KT]{?@?!02|06 @2:6} việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:3\index[KT]{?@?!037|03 @37:3}6-38\index[KT]{?@?!037|036 @37:3\index[KT]{?@?!037|03 @37:3}6-38}).
```

I want it to do the indexing like that:

```
12 =>  thiêu (30:33). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6 việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38\index[KT]{?@?!037|036 @37:36-38}).
13 =>  thiêu (30:33\index[KT]{?@?!030|033 @30:33}). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6\index[KT]{?@?!02|06 @2:6} việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38\index[KT]{?@?!037|036 @37:36-38}).
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?  It's not clear what the conversion requirements are, but this matches your target strings:

```py
import re

line = "thiêu (30:33). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6 việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38)."
want1 = 'thiêu (30:33). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6 việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38\index[KT]{?@?!037|036 @37:36-38}).'
want2 = 'thiêu (30:33\index[KT]{?@?!030|033 @30:33}). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6\index[KT]{?@?!02|06 @2:6} việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38\index[KT]{?@?!037|036 @37:36-38}).'

line1 = re.sub(r'(\d+):(\d+)-(\d+)', r'\1:\2-\3\\index[KT]{?@?!0\1|0\2 @\1:\2-\3}', line)
print(line1)
assert line1 == want1
line2 = re.sub(r'(\d+):((\d+)(?:-\d+)?)', r'\1:\2\\index[KT]{?@?!0\1|0\3 @\1:\2}', line)
print(line2)
assert line2 == want2
```

Output:

```
thiêu (30:33). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6 việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38\index[KT]{?@?!037|036 @37:36-38}).
thiêu (30:33\index[KT]{?@?!030|033 @30:33}). chương 36-37 ghi lại tất cả những  2:6\index[KT]{?@?!02|06 @2:6} việc này đã thật sự xảyra như thế nào (37:36-38\index[KT]{?@?!037|036 @37:36-38}).
```

Comment: Thank You.
But the line2 should take as input the output of line1. Since the regex pattern for 30:33 is part of the pattern for 37:36-38 it become hard to separate. 

line = re.sub(r'([^–])(\d+):(\d+)(\d+)(?!\-)', r'\1\2:\3\\index[KT]{?@?!0\2|0\3 @\2:\3}', line) will   be fine for 30:33 but not for 2:3.